# Select data from table B where a field in table B matches table A (php mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains a list of livestock ("livestock"), this gets regularly updated and changed. I also have a second table ("description") containing two columns "Scientific" and "Description".

I need to select the Description field from the description table when the Scientific field in both tables matches but not sure how best to do this.

Hope this makes sense, any help is much appreciated

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do this, but I am sure that you will need to do a table join.

Comment: `SELECT a.*, b.Description FROM livestock a INNER JOIN description b ON a.Scientific = b.Scientific` -- try that.

Comment: Can you give us a table creation query you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mismatches between two of your tables (meaning not all rows in `livestock` have respective rows in `description`) you most likely have to use an `OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT` or `RIGHT`) to achieve your goal

```sql
SELECT l.*, d.description
  FROM livestock l LEFT JOIN description d
    ON l.scientific = d.scientific
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c60e/1)** demo

Further reading

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

**On a side note:** *When asking query related questions, especially when you don't provide your version of the query, please at least help those who want to help you and provide your table(s) schema, sample data, and desired output based on it. Better yet spend one minute and create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your sample data.*

Comment: @user2647237 Did it solve your problem? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming table_a is the name of the livestock table and table_b is the table with the description in it, you'll want to join the tables on the 'scientific' field.

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.Description
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_a.Scientific = table_b.Scientific
```

You'll want to replace `table_a` and `table_b` with the correct table names.